# Tab and return character sequences for solaris?

Tags: solaris, special-characters

Is tab character in "\t" or "\r\t" in Solaris ?
And the new line character sequence \n or \r\n ?

thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- \t = tab
- \r = carraige return
- \n =
  newline

Solaris standard line delimiter is \n

Answer (score 1):

A tab character is "\t", always. A newline on Solaris is "\n", the only time a newline is "\r\n" is in DOS/Windows land.

Answer (score 0):

Tab is always "\t", carriage-return is "\r", and newline is "\n".

To be very specific, the end-of-line (EOL) marker on DOS-based systems is "\r\n". It's apparently just a carriage-return on early Apple systems, and just newline on most others.

Comment: Apple II and every Mac OS up to 9 use "\r"  Anything after that uses "\n"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I forgot about the Apple behavior; never had to program one of those.