# Issues writing to a file in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, newline, solaris

I am running this script on solaris.  I am trying to write the real, user, and system times to a file, each on a separate line.  However, this code instead writes them out together on the same line with a bunch of unknown character boxes.  How can I get each of the times on their own separate line?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = "time echo 'hi' 2>&1 | tee -a runtimes.log";
system ($command);
```

Comment: actually, it worked somewhat, im editing my question

Comment: re: edit: Are you expecting that `open` to do anything? Because it is not. Also, at the end of the script, you need neither `close` nor `exit`, as those things are done automatically when the script ends.

Comment: I tried in AIX and it's printing everything in newline. Is it still not working for you? If yes, then what exactly not working. Also, as @TLP mentioned you don't need that `exit` in your script.

Comment: I cannot get the times printed to my file on separate lines.

Comment: @Stephen How do you know they are not on separate lines? You view the file in some browser? Which browser?

Comment: @TLP I am viewing it in notepad.  It is important that they are on separate lines because I need to chomp them out separately for a another script I have.  As of now it is not working on solaris.

Comment: @Stephen Notepad on Solaris? Notepad is notoriously barebones, and it will often interpret some symbols incorrectly. If you print `\n` to a file in perl, you can trust that it is there. It is only notepad who is not showing it properly.

Comment: Chomp is still unable to recognize the new lines though.  I have an equivalent version of this script that I run on Windows and it has no issues with newline.  I am able to chomp each line on Windows too.  Chomp doesn't seem to work when you can't see the newlines in notepad.

Comment: [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) removes any trailing string corresponding to `$/`. On most systems, that is `\n`. If you are unsure. check what `$/` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably get better results as well as more maintainable code if you use perl code (either `times` or `POSIX::times`) for getting the system/user times.

```
$command="ls -lR";
@before{real,user,system,chuser,chsystem}=(time(),times());
system $command;
@after{real,user,system,chuser,chsystem}=(time(),times());
print "real @{[ $after{real}-$before{real} ]}\n";
print "user @{[ $after{chuser}-$before{chuser} ]}\n";
print "sys  @{[ $after{chsystem}-$before{chsystem} ]}\n";
```

or the POSIX version:

```
use POSIX qw(times sysconf);
$clocks_per_second=POSIX::sysconf( &POSIX::_SC_CLK_TCK );
$command="ls -lR";
@before{real,user,system,chuser,chsystem}=(POSIX::times());
system $command;
@after{real,user,system,chuser,chsystem}=(POSIX::times());
printf "real  %2.2f\n", ($after{real}-$before{real})/$clocks_per_second;
printf "user  %2.2f\n", ($after{chuser}-$before{chuser})/$clocks_per_second;
printf "sys   %2.2f\n", ($after{chsystem}-$before{chsystem})/$clocks_per_second;
```

Comment: I really like how this solution would look.  However I can not get it to run on my machine.  I did add 'use POSIX;' at the top and no luck.  How would your code look when it is fully functional? Thanks.

Comment: `time` and `times` are builtin functions, so this _should_ work as-is.  The posix version returns slightly different values (clock ticks rather than seconds) so conversion is needed, but in exchange you get higher resolution on the realtime number.  For the POSIX version, add `use POSIX qw(times sysconf);` and change `(time(),times())` to `(POSIX::times())`.  To convert to seconds, divide the differences by `$POSIX::sysconf( &POSIX::_SC_CLK_TCK );`  (sysconf value for clock ticks per second)

Comment: Yeah the posix one is way more accurate.  The only change i would make to this for my issue would be to replace the "\n" with "\r\n".  But this is definitely the most helpful answer.  thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Solaris standard line delimiter is `\n`, so your code seems right. Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975142/tab-and-return-character-sequences-for-solaris).

Possibly your problem has to do with the text editor you are using to view the file...

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Check the output of both your `open` and `system` commands.
- Print an extra blank line before you close the file.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;   #No need for -w when using this

my $command = "time ls 2>&1 | tee -a runtimes.log";
open (FILE, '>>runtimes.log') 
    or die qq(Can't open "runtimes.log for writing\n);

my $error = system ($command);
if ($error) {
    die qq(Error in executing command "$command": $?\n);
}
print "\n";
close FILE;
exit 0;
```